# Is proto-type design pattern a right approach here for the following situation - looking for creational part only?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am writing a transport layer sniffer. The packets from the transport layer will be analysed here. Here, the transport layer - packet types can be - UDP or TCP. Also, there will be a lot of tcp and udp packets. So, I need to keep creating and deleting it. Many a time, I need to refer the previous TCP packet.

My solution - Create a proto-type design pattern - the base class - transport packet and sub-class will be UDP and TCP. If I never receive UDP packet, then I will not instantiate it. 
Thus, I can keep creating the TCP or UDP class object to analyse the packet.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype pattern is most useful when you have many derived classes or classes that are complicated to create and you want to be able to configure a factory at runtime by plugging in pre-created prototypes.

With the prototype pattern you still need to keep creating and deleting the packet objects. It is just that the create is done by cloning a prototype.

In your case, if there are only two types of packet and they are not too complicated to create I think a simple factory would be sufficient.

If you find that creating and deleting your packet objects is impacting performance you might want to consider the [Object Pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) or [Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). With the Object Pool pattern you keep a pool of initialized objects ready to use so you don't have to keep creating and deleting objects. With the Flyweight pattern you don't create an object for each packet at all but keep the state of each packet outside of the class.